# Arrange pairs of numbers so that members of adjacent pairs are equal

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I would like to arrange the following items, forming the longest chain possible starting with 12-8 and matching the numbers end to end.

My items are 7-4, 11-8, 11-11, 1-0, 4-2, 7-5, 10-8, 7-3, 10-5, 7-2, 9-8, 12-8, 0-0, 11-10

The longest possible chain is 12-8, 8-11, 11-11, 11-10, 10-5, 5-7, 7-4, 4-2, 2-7, 7-3

I tried iterating over the array of items and taking the first value that matches the number I'm looking for but it doesn't result in the longest chain. My method gets me: 12-8, 8-11, 11-11, 11-10, 10-8, 8-9

How can I write a proper sorting algorithm for this task?

Comment: If you enter "domino" in the search you'll find many related questions.

Comment: I see in longest possible chain... one item is  8-11 but it is not in your item list.. so we can swap value of that item?

Comment: **1.** Can you have repeated items? For example, `7-4` and `7-4`. And **2.**, is there a max defined value of your items?

Comment: (How can _anyone_ write a sorting algorithm for domino pieces such that the _longest trail_ for a given input shows up in the output?) - Not at all. Having the pieces ordered _can_ help finding/enumerating matching pieces - with very few different values for each side, there are more attractive approaches.

Answer (score 2):

you need recursion, but it might not work on a bigger data set:
something like this.

DISCLAIMER: This is probably not the most optimized solution (complexity O(N!)) but it is very simple to implement if you are allowed to use recursion

(this is not objective-c code, it's an algorithm, translate it yourself, sorry i don't know objective-c)

```
list function sortTupleList(list a, list b) //b is the current list
  list biggest = newlist()
  int target = b.last()[1]
  for(tuple k in a)
    if (k[0] == target)
      list n = sortTupleList(a.remove(k), b.add(k))
      if(n.size > biggest.size())
        biggest = n
      end if
    end if
  end for
  if (biggest == emptylist)
    return b
  else
    return biggest
end function


list function caller(list a)
  list b = newlist()
  b.add(12-8)
  a.remove(12-8)
  return sortTupleList(a,b)
end function
```

This function will test every single pattern starting from 12-8 and compare their size

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the size of your problem ( `n` number of the tiles ) you can choose either of the following methods:

1- Bruteforce: You can check all the possible configurations of tiles using backtrack that would result in an algorithm of `O(n!)` complexity.

2- [Bitmask Dynamic Programming](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bitmasking-and-dynamic-programming-set-1-count-ways-to-assign-unique-cap-to-every-person/): You can use dynamic programming with the help of bitmask to reduce your search space. This approach will result in algorithm of `O(2^n * n)`.

Answer (score 2):

I've looked at the problem in a graph-theoretic perspective, which gives some insights about the problem, and provides some heuristics that may be used to solve the problem efficiently.

First, construct a graph such that every item you are given corresponds to an edge of the graph. For example, if your input given as: 1-2, 2-3; you construct a graph with nodes: 1, 2, 3; and edges (1, 2), (2, 3).

Thereafter, you can see that your problem is identical to finding the longest trail, i.e., the longest path that does not contain any edge more than one. Unfortunately, this problem is known to be NP-hard, as discussed in this [question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20682/is-the-longest-trail-problem-easier-than-the-longest-path-problem). So, we cannot hope to find a polynomial algorithm to solve this problem.

However, this problem is actually very similar to the problem of [Eularian Path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path). However, in an Eularian path you traverse all edges. And it has a very simple solution:

> An undirected graph has an Eulerian path if and only if exactly zero
>   or two vertices have odd degree, and if all of its vertices with
>   nonzero degree belong to a single connected component.

So in order to solve your problem, you take the connected component of the graph that contains the item you want to start with. You cannot possibly reach the items that are not in this connected component. Therefore, you can forget about all of the remaining edges of the graph.

Then, you simply count the degrees of each node, and check if that graph has an Eulerian path by the preceding definition. If it has, then you're lucky. Because you can't possibly have a chain longer than this path.

And you can compute this chain easily by [Fleury's Algorithm](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fleurys-algorithm-for-printing-eulerian-path/).

However, if this component does not have an Eualirian path, then you at least know that there does not exist a chain of the size of the edges of this component or more.

[Handshaking Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma) tells us:

> Every undirected graph has an even number of vertices with odd degree.

If there does not exists an Eulerian path, then we know that we have *2k* nodes with odd degrees where *k > 1*. So we need to remove minimum number of edges edges so that we have *k = 1*. However, you need to take into account that when you remove some of the edges, remaining edges may not be connected.

So the best heuristic that comes to my mind is to find edges such that both of its vertices have odd degrees, and removing it doesn't tear the connected component apart. If we can find such *k - 1* vertices, then when we remove them we will stil have a connected component and we will have only 2 vertices with odd degrees. Therefore we can find the longest chain easily, again by finding an Eulerian path using Fleury's algorithm.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. The graph is undirected, so the orientation doesn't matter. Notice that in the example that OP has given, some of the items are reversed. I don't get what you mean by a vertex being available. A vertex can be connected to many edges.

Comment: @גלעדברקן: `edges in this graph depend on the 'orientation' of their vertices` - from the example, it would seem orientation does _not_ matter (quite like domino): `11-8` is given thus, but `8-11` gets used.

Comment: Oh, no! It's an edge.

Comment: You just build a graph with nodes 8, 10, 11. And those items are the edges. This is actually the formal definition of a graph. I don't understand why you are so confused.

Comment: It would be 4. I guess you are confused with loops, i.e. edges such as (11, 11). As another heuristic for the problem, you should never remove loops.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the numbers as vertices and the pairs as edges of a graph (so there may be some multi-edges). Now your problem is reduced to finding the longest path in the graph where vertices (but not edges) may be repeated.

Comment: quoted from @ami-tavori: "For arguing NP-Completeness, the reduction should be the other way. It should argue that given any graph instance (which can also contain loops), there's an instance of this problem whose solution is a loop-free longest path in the original graph. "

Comment: This is just the adjacency representation of a graph.

Comment: It's not the longest path problem. In longest path problem, you are not allowed to repeat vertices, (consequently edges), but in this problem (known as longest trail problem) you are not allowed to repeat only edges, which is more relaxed. But it is still NP-Hard anyway.

Comment: @errorist You're right. I forgot that 'longest path' means 'longest simple path.' Do you have a reference that shows it's still NP-Hard with repeated vertices?

Answer (score 1):

Keeping with errorist's idea, we can define a state for a graph as the number of edges, the number of vertices with odd degrees, a hash of vertices and their connections, and a set of edges with an odd degree vertex. We can prioritize the states by the number of edges subtracted by `min(2, number of vertices with odd degree)` or by zero if the number of odd degree vertices equals 2.

Below is an attempt at a JavaScript implementation, utilizing a heap for a priority queue. Each edge with an odd degree vertex is removed by turn, the graph is analyzed and split into any separate components when applicable, and each component is pushed to the priority queue. The loop exits early, hopefully guaranteeing that the first graph returned with an Eulerian path also has the longest such achievable.

```js
var Heap = function (f){
  this.heap = [];
  this.isPriority = f || function(a,b){ return a > b; };
}

Heap.prototype.put = function(val){
  this.heap.push(val);

  var i = this.heap.length - 1,
      parent = i - 1 >> 1;

  while (i !== 0 && this.isPriority(this.heap[i],this.heap[parent])){
    this.heap[i] = this.heap[parent];
    this.heap[parent] = val;
    i = parent;
    parent = i - 1 >> 1
  }

  return this.heap;
}

Heap.prototype.get = function(val){
  if (this.heap.length === 0){
    return null;
    
  } else if (this.heap.length === 1){
    return this.heap.pop();
  }

  var first = this.heap[0],
      last = this.heap.pop(),
      i = 0;

  this.heap[i] = last;

  while (true){
    var j = 2*i + 1;

    if (this.heap[j] === undefined){
      break;
    }

    if (this.heap[2*i + 2] !== undefined && this.isPriority(this.heap[2*i + 2],this.heap[j])){
      j = 2*i + 2;
    }

    if (this.isPriority(this.heap[j],this.heap[i])){
      this.heap[i] = this.heap[j];
      this.heap[j] = last;
      i = j;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }

  return first;
}

function makeGraphs(graph){
  // separate disconnected graphs
  var graphs = [],
      index = 0,
      visited = new Set();
      
  function traverse(v){  
    visited.add(v);
    
    var vs = graph.vertices[v];
    
    if (vs.length > 0){
      graphs[index].vertices[v] = [];
    }
    
    for (var i in vs){
      graphs[index].vertices[v].push(vs[i]);
      graphs[index].numEdges++;
      
      if (!visited.has(vs[i])){
        traverse(vs[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  
  for (var i in graph.vertices){
    if (!visited.has(i) && graph.vertices[i].length >0){
      graphs.push({vertices: {}, numEdges: 0});
      traverse(i);
      index++;
    }
  }
  
  // enumerate odd degree vertices and their edges
  for (var i=0; i<graphs.length; i++){
    graphs[i].numEdges /= 2;
  
    graphs[i].numOddDegreeVertices = 0;
    graphs[i].edgesWithOddDegreeVertices = new Set();
  
    for (var u in graphs[i].vertices){
      if (graphs[i].vertices[u].length & 1){
        graphs[i].numOddDegreeVertices++;
        
        graphs[i].vertices[u].forEach(function(v){
          var edge = u + '-' + v;
          
          if (!graphs[i].edgesWithOddDegreeVertices.has(edge) 
           && !graphs[i].edgesWithOddDegreeVertices.has(v+'-'+u)){
            graphs[i].edgesWithOddDegreeVertices.add(edge);
          }
        });
      }    
    }
  }
  
  return graphs;
}

function potentialEdges(graph){
  if (graph.numOddDegreeVertices === 2){
    return graph.numEdges;
  }
  return graph.numEdges - Math.min(2,graph.numOddDegreeVertices);
}

function removeEdge(graph,edge){
  var vertices = edge.split("-"),
      u = vertices[0],
      v = vertices[1];
      
  graph.vertices[u].splice(graph.vertices[u].indexOf(v),1);
  graph.vertices[v].splice(graph.vertices[v].indexOf(u),1);
  graph.edgesWithOddDegreeVertices.delete(edge);
  
  return graph;
}

function hasEulerianPath(graph){
  if (graph.numOddDegreeVertices === 2 || graph.numOddDegreeVertices === 0){
    return true;  
  }
  return false;
}

function copyGraph(graph){
  var copy = {
    vertices: {},
    numEdges: graph.numEdges,
    numOddDegreeVertices: graph.numOddDegreeVertices,
    edgesWithOddDegreeVertices: new Set(graph.edgesWithOddDegreeVertices)
  };
  
  for (var v in graph.vertices){
    copy.vertices[v] = graph.vertices[v].slice();
  }
  
  return copy;
}

function f(ps){
  var edges = [],
      edgeIndexes = {},
      graph = {vertices: {}};
      
  for (var i=0; i<ps.length; i++){
    edgeIndexes[ps[i]] = i;
    edges[i] = ps[i].split("-");
  }
  
  for (var i=0; i<edges.length; i++){  
    if (graph.vertices[edges[i][0]] !== undefined){
      graph.vertices[edges[i][0]].push(edges[i][1]);
      
    } else {
      graph.vertices[edges[i][0]] = [edges[i][1]];
    }
    
    if (graph.vertices[edges[i][1]] !== undefined){
      graph.vertices[edges[i][1]].push(edges[i][0]);
      
    } else {
      graph.vertices[edges[i][1]] = [edges[i][0]];
    }
  }
  
  var heap = new Heap(function(a,b){
    return potentialEdges(a) > potentialEdges(b);
  });
  
  var graphs = makeGraphs(graph);

  for (var i=0; i<graphs.length; i++){
    heap.put(graphs[i]);
  }
  
  var current = heap.get();

  while (current !== null){
    if (current.numEdges > 1 && hasEulerianPath(current)){
      return current;
    }
    
    current.edgesWithOddDegreeVertices.forEach(function(edge){
      var copy = copyGraph(current);

      removeEdge(copy,edge);
      graphs = makeGraphs(copy);
      
      for (var i=0; i<graphs.length; i++){
        heap.put(graphs[i]);
      }
    });
    
    current = heap.get();
  }
 
  return "The longest chain appears to be one edge only.";
}

var input = ['7-4','11-8','11-11','1-0','4-2','7-5','10-8','7-3','10-5','7-2','9-8','12-8','0-0','11-10'];

console.log('Input: ' + input.join(', '));
console.log('---');
console.log('Output: ' + JSON.stringify(f(input)));
console.log('---');
console.log("OP's example solution: 12-8, 8-11, 11-11, 11-10, 10-5, 5-7, 7-4, 4-2, 2-7, 7-3");
```