# Make Longest Possible Word Chain with String Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to make a program that sorts an array of words into the longest possible "chain" (each word starts with the letter that the previous word ends in). An example chain is Uta**h** --> **H**awai**i** --> **I**dah**o** --> **O**regon.

I've been trying to figure this out for about 2 hours now. The method I've been using is brute force, trying to generate all possible chains and then finding the longest one. The problem I'm having is that I can't figure out how to not get caught in a loop when finding chains.
I tried searching to see if this was already answered on StackOverflow, and I did find an answered question about this problem, but it was in Python and when I tested the accepted solution it failed on large lists.

Here's the general idea:

```
  var words = ["Alabama","Alaska","Arizona","Arkansas","California","Colorado","Connecticut","Delaware","Florida","Georgia","Hawaii","Idaho","Illinois","Indiana","Iowa","Kansas","Kentucky","Louisiana","Maine","Maryland","Massachusetts","Michigan","Minnesota","Mississippi","Missouri","Montana","New Hampshire","New Jersey","New Mexico","New York","North Carolina","North Dakota","Ohio","Oklahoma","Oregon","Pennsylvania","Rhode Island","South Carolina","South Dakota","Tennessee","Texas","Utah","Vermont","Virginia","Washington","West Virginia","Wisconsin","Wyoming"];

function longestChain(wordArray) {
  var allChains = [];
  for(var x = 0; x < words.length; x++) {
    /* I'm completely lost here
       store all chains generated with this start in the allChains array
       each chain should be an array
       example: ["Utah","Hawaii","Idaho","Oregon","New York","Kentucky"]
    */
  }
  var max = [0,0];
  for(var x = 0; x < allChains.length; x++) {
    if(allChains[x].length > max[0]) {
      max[0] = allChains[x].length;
      max[1] = x;
    }
  }
  return allChains[max[1]];
}
```

So basically I need a way to find all the possible chains without looping.

Comment: Try getting an array of all "first characters" of the words as one array, then all of the "last characters" of the words as a second array. Then sort them by occurrence, then join the least frequent to each other until you run out.

Comment: Frequency and a greedy approach might lead to an dead end without being close to the optimal result. Way too easy to run into a dead end.

Comment: This feels like a sort of [Longest Path Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) so enumerating all possible chains might indeed be a good start.

Comment: @SaiBot This is definitely the longest path problem. For an undirected graph, this is NP hard. But this is a directed graph: each word is a vertex and and an edge exists from vertex A to B if the last letter of A is the first letter of B. For a DAG it's solvable in polynomial time, but this graph may have cycles, and I don't quite remember how to find the longest path in a cyclic directed graph.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrange pairs of numbers so that members of adjacent pairs are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39319661/arrange-pairs-of-numbers-so-that-members-of-adjacent-pairs-are-equal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below recursive function `getChains()` will build you all the possible chains for your use case and stores them in the `allChains` variable.

As I mentioned in the comments, this problem feels like a [Longest Path Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem). If this is the case you cannot do much better than a brute-force solution. Thus the following solution will become very slow if the words array will grow larger, but for the given words it runs in a couple of seconds.

```js
var words = ["Alabama","Alaska","Arizona","Arkansas","California","Colorado","Connecticut","Delaware","Florida","Georgia","Hawaii","Idaho","Illinois","Indiana","Iowa","Kansas","Kentucky","Louisiana","Maine","Maryland","Massachusetts","Michigan","Minnesota","Mississippi","Missouri","Montana","New Hampshire","New Jersey","New Mexico","New York","North Carolina","North Dakota","Ohio","Oklahoma","Oregon","Pennsylvania","Rhode Island","South Carolina","South Dakota","Tennessee","Texas","Utah","Vermont","Virginia","Washington","West Virginia","Wisconsin","Wyoming"];

var allChains = [];
var usedWords = [];
var currentChain = [];

getChains(currentChain, words, usedWords, allChains)

for(var i = 0; i < allChains.length; i++){
  document.write(allChains[i])
  document.write("<br>")
}

function getChains(currentChain, words, usedWords, allChains){
  var found = false;
  for(var x = 0; x < words.length; x++){
    if((currentChain.length == 0 || currentChain[currentChain.length-1].slice(-1) == words[x].toLowerCase().charAt(0)) && !usedWords.includes(x)){
      currentChain.push(words[x]);
      found = true;
      usedWords.push(x);
      getChains(currentChain, words, usedWords, allChains);
    }
  }
  if(!found){
      allChains.push(currentChain.slice());
  }
  currentChain.pop();
  usedWords.pop();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, this is a longest path finding problem.

If the graph is bidirectional, the solution is NP hard. You have to solve it using
recursion or backtrack. You can also solve it using musking dp if the input size is small. Someone already shared a solution based on recursion.

If the graph is directed but acyclic, it has solution. You can solve it using algorithm like topological sort.[Link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-longest-path-directed-acyclic-graph/)

But if the graph is directed cyclic graph, it behaves like bidirectional graph. So solution is np hard.

Your problem is a directed cyclic graph.
For example,
 Let words={"abc","cde","efa"}
 By using these words if we make a graph then word[0] will be connected to word[1], word[1] will be connected to word[2] and word[2] will be connected to word[0].
 So it creates a cyclic graph.

Answer (score 0):

You could separate the words who start and ends with the same letter and take the rest for building a tree. Then get the longest words arrays and try to add the words with the same letter start/ending.

```js
function getLongestWords(words) {
    function getTree(word, seen) {
        var last = word.slice(-1).toUpperCase();
        if (!data[last]) return {};
        return data[last].reduce(getChildren(seen.concat(word)), {});
    }

    function getChildren(seen) {
        return function (r, w) {
            if (!seen.includes(w)) r[w] = getTree(w, seen);
            return r;
        };
    }

    function getLength(array) {
        return array.reduce((l, { length }) => l + length, 0);
    }

    function getLongest(object, result = [], parts = []) {
        var keys = Object.keys(object);
        if (!keys.length) {
            if (getLength(parts) > getLength(result[0] || [])) {
                result.length = 0;
                result.push(parts);
            } else if (getLength(parts) === getLength(result[0])) {
                result.push(parts);
            }
            return result;
        }
        keys.forEach(k => getLongest(object[k], result, parts.concat(k)));
        return result;
    }

    var notSame = [],
        same = {},
        data = words.reduce((r, w) => {
            var key = w[0],
                last = w.slice(-1);
            if (key === last.toUpperCase()) {
                same[key] = same[key] || { words: [], used: [] };
                same[key].words.push(w);
            } else {
                r[key] = r[key] || [];
                r[key].push(w);
                notSame.push(w);
            }
            return r;
        }, {}),
        tree = notSame.reduce(getChildren([]), {});

    return getLongest(tree).map((a, i) => {
        var key = a[0][0];
        if (key in same && !same[key].used.includes(i)) {
            same[key].used.push(i);
            return same[key].words.concat(a);
        }
        return a.reduce((r, w) => {
            key = w.slice(-1).toUpperCase();
            r.push(w);
            if (key in same && !same[key].used.includes(i)) {
                same[key].used.push(i);
                r.push(...same[key].words);
            }
            return r;
        }, []);
    });
}

var words1 = ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"],
    words2 = ["Abc", "Cde", "Efa"];

console.log(getLongestWords(words1));
console.log(getLongestWords(words2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: for var words = ["abc","cde","efa"] , what should be the output?

Comment: @mahbubcseju, it works with `["Abc", "Cde", "Efa"]` and you get three result sets.